# Add quotes at the beginning and end of each element in list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings that I want to encapsulate in quotes and separate with comma and output as single string.

Right now I got only the comma part like so `string.Join(",", list);`. This generates output like so `Id, Name, Price`. However I want to add quotes to every item so it will output it like so `"Id", "Name", "Price"`.

Right now I'm looping through every item in list copying it's value and then adding the quotes but I suspect it is possible to do using LINQ.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
String.Join(",", myList.Select(x => String.Format("\"{0}\"", x));
```

Comment: String.Join(",", myList.Select(x => $"\"{x}\"")); is cleaner and does the same

Answer (score 7):

> I suspect it is possible to do using LINQ

You are correct:

```
var result = string.Join(",", list.Select(s => '"' + s + '"') );
```

> Right now I'm looping through every item in list copying it's value and then adding the quotes

Well, that's what Linq is doing behind-the-scenes; it's just wrapping it in a `.Select` extension method.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Format("\"{0}\"", string.Join("\",\"", list);
```

Creates a list and then adds the missing quotes.

First list: element1","element2","element3

Final output: "element1","element2","element3"